# how to overwrite component use xlinkHref on pcss file

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I create a pcss file to overwritten some icon path from the component I import to use it?
Under my project, I need to import a component from packages that include some icon like

```
      <svg className="icon">
        <use xlinkHref="icon_link_16x16" />
      </svg>
```

however, I would like to link to different icon so I create a pcss file like

```
.icon {
src: url('new_icon_link')
}
```

but it does not work. so how can I overwritten the new icon path `new_icon_link`  from the original from component `icon_link_16x16`?

Comment: What is a `pcss` file?

Comment: PostCSS file https://www.oliverdavies.uk/blog/using-pcss-extension-postcss-webpack-encore